# Running a .BAT file in JAVA without opening a command prompt

Tags: java

I've been trying to run an executable `.bat` file in Java using the line:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("call " + batFile);
```

But it returns an error

> Could not start process with commandLine nullCreateProcess: call *batfilename here* error=2
>   IOException: Create Process: call *batfilename here* error=2

I managed to bypass this by replacing the `String` in the `exec()` function with `"cmd /c start " + batFile` but this opens a command prompt which is not allowed.

Are there workarounds to this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(batFile);`?

Comment: @JasonC Works fine for me...

Comment: @JasonC It can be tricky depending on what you are doing...are you waiting for the process to complete?

Comment: @MadProgrammer No. Maybe that's it... I'll just believe you without testing. My attention span has already been massively exceeded.

Comment: @JasonC I know the feeling and my day has just started.  I need another test, starting `calc` and copying a file, I had to close `calc` before the copy would work and the file would complete, but this was as expected ;)

Comment: Hi guys, no. 'Runtime.getRuntime().exec(batFile);' doesn't work. I'm starting to think that our application may have some file write permission issues since it doesn't generate an error or exception but also doesn't generate a file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try running the batch file directly, for example...

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Test.bat");
pb.redirectError();
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    try (InputStream inputStream = p.getInputStream()) {
        int in = -1;
        while ((in = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)in);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Exited with " + p.waitFor());
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

This was the batch file...

```
@echo Hello World
```

(I know, massive) and the code outputted...

```
Hello World
Exited with 0
```

Comment: Hi! Works perfectly! Thanks a bunch! So if I need to add parameters to the .BAT file, how'd I accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Followup, if I need to add parameters to the .BAT file, how'd I accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: `ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("C:/Test.bat", param1, param2, param3, etc..)`

Answer (score 0):

A little late but for others who want to try I found the /B of start command.

```
String[] command = { "cmd", "/C", "start", "/B", "test.bat" };
File path = new File("C:/Users/Me/Desktop/dir/");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command, null, path);
```